# Angular Pipe -- Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Tags: angular, typescript

Coming across the following error when creating this time ago pipe:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

```
if (value) {
      const seconds = Math.floor(
        (+new Date() - +new Date(Number(value))) / 1000
      );
      if (seconds < 60) {
        return "Just now";
      }
      const intervals = {
        year: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60,
        month: (52 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60) / 12,
        week: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
        day: 24 * 60 * 60,
        hour: 60 * 60,
        minute: 60,
        second: 1
      };
      let counter;
      for (const i of Object.keys(intervals)) {
        counter = Math.floor(seconds / intervals[i]);
        if (counter > 0) {
          if (counter === 1) {
            return counter + " " + i + " ago"; // singular
          } else {
            return counter + " " + i + "s ago"; // plural
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return value;
```

```
intervals[i]
```

This portion is causing the error.

I've tried a few different ways of changing the type or accessing this object but I'm coming up short in the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Typescript gives you this error because you haven't declared that this object has keys of type `string` that return a `number`.

```js
const intervals: { [key: string]: number } = {
...
}
```

Keys can be of type `string`, `number`, `symbol`, or `template literal` and you can specify that each returns a different type. If you do not specify, then the type checker can only assume the return type is `any`, and it will not be able to catch bugs in subsequent code.

Doc reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures

Answer (score 1):

I added:

```
"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
```

to tsconfig.json to fix this.